# Getting errors in Alamofire after installing another dependency " pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 3.0' "

Tags: alamofire

I am working on a project in swift.I used Alamofire using pod and it was working fine. But after adding another third party "pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 3.0'" and updating pod ,I am getting errors in Alamofire. I also removed Alamofire and added it again, still it's giving the same error. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Solved!! I was updating the pod after adding a library which was upgrading the version of Alamofire which was mismatching ith the deployment target.I changed the version of alamofire and install the pod again.Now it is working fine. Thanks